# save file in local machine which was generate in remote machine?

Tags: ansible

**test.yml**

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: username
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the script
      command: sh /home/username/top.sh
```

**top.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
top > system.txt
```

I run **test.yml** in local machine, it will run the shell script in remote machine and save the command in **system.txt** file.

location of **top.sh**: remote, location of **system.txt**: remote

**But I am looking for**

location of **top.sh**: local (but I need to run this command in remote), location of **system.txt**: local

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`synchronize`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module to copy files from local to remote or from remote to local host. For example

```
- name: 'Copy run.sh to remote machine'
  synchronize:
    mode: push
    src: top.sh
    dest: /home/username

- name: Execute the script
  command: sh /home/username/top.sh

- name: 'Copy system.txt to local machine'
  synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: /home/username/system.txt
    dest: .
```

Note: for the `synchronize` module to work you will need to have `rsync` installed on the hosts.

Comment: Wow you great. in 'execute the script'  command does not get end it will generate content dynamically(infinite loop) so it does not come to the next step(store in local machine). how to overcome this situation?

Comment: @BilalUsean you need to add some kind of timeout in either your top.sh script, or using ansible with async and wait_for, but that's a separate question you should ask.