# how to handle never ending loop linux command - ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943550/save-file-in-local-machine-which-was-generate-in-remote-machine) to understand what I have done.

**short description**

I need to run top command in remote machine and get that result content then save that file in local machine

**test.yml**

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: 'Copy top.sh to remote machine'
      synchronize: mode=push  src=top.sh dest=/home/raj

    - name: Execute the script
      command: sh /home/raj/top.sh
      async: 45
      poll: 5

    - name: 'Copy system.txt to local machine'
      synchronize: mode=pull src=system.txt dest=/home/bu
```

**top.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 top > system.txt
```

**problem**

**top.sh** never end so I am trying to every five seconds poll the result and copy into local machine but it is not working.it throws below error.

```
stderr: top: failed tty get
<job 351267881857.24744> FAILED on 192.168.1.7
```

note: I got this error only when I include async and poll option

Comment: What is your goal?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why are you running `top` non-interactively?  There almost certainly is a better method to go about doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: if you have any alternate method please mention in answer. I have updated my question @XiongChiamiov

Comment: I still don't know the answers to those questions.  It's very likely that you shouldn't be running `top` at all, nor using Ansible to run it, to achieve what you want, but I don't know what you want to be able to give any more specific advice.  I can *guess* that you want a more full-fledged monitoring system, or perhaps need a quick-and-dirty solution that involves running `top -n 1 >> top.log` in a crontab.

Comment: I am wondering for down votes. please mention the reason for the down vote because I need to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Bilal I Hope this is useful for you

your syntax: using **poll:5** follw this link http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html

poll is using wait on the task to complete. But top command doesn,t stop until use stop or system shutdown. use **poll:0**

" Alternatively, if you do not need to wait on the task to complete, you may “fire and forget” by specifying a poll value of 0:"

Now forget the task, collect top result  file from remote and store to local use below syntax

---

```
    - hosts: webservers
      remote_user: root
      tasks:
        - name: 'Copy top.sh to remote machine'
          synchronize: mode=push  src=top.sh dest=/home/raj

        - name: collecting top result
          command: sh /home/raj/top.sh
          async: 45
          poll: 0

        - name: 'Copy top command result to local machine'
          synchronize: mode=pull src=/home/raj/Top.txt  dest=/home/raj2/Documents/Ansible
```

top.sh:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  top -b > /home/raj/Top.txt
```

This is works for me. ping me if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to run the `top` command itself, or is this just an example of a long-running program you want to monitor?

The error you're receiving:

> top: failed tty get

...happens when the `top` command isn't running in a real terminal session.  The mode of `ssh` that Ansible uses doesn't support all the console features that the full blown terminal session would have - which is what `top` expects.

Comment: but without include async, top command work in remote machine and generate the output system.txt in remote machine now I am trying to poll the system.txt changes and copy that system.txt changes to local machine